# Android: For how long Firebase will remember its login?

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase auth in my application. Currently I am using only the email and password mechanism. Below is the code I use.

```
private void signInUser(String email, String password)
    {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign In Failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign In Success!!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

Below is how I register a user

```
private void createAccount(final String email, String password)
    {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signup Failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            saveInDatabase(email);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signup Success!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...


                    }
                });
    }
```

It is true that firebase is remembering whether the user is signed in or not. That is good. But, for how long it will remember? 1 week? 1 Month? Forever? Until phone is restarted or even after phone is restarted?

Or else, do we have to set the remember time pragmatically? In that case how do we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity of the user is remembered indefinitely (or until you sign out). But their credentials (or rather, whether their token is still valid) are re-checked every hour.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. so, the user will "not be" logged out until he manually log out? How the token can be invalid? I am trying to find whether the user has to re login in every hour.

Comment: Your user won't have to re-authenticate unless there has been a compelling event (e.g. their password has changed) when the token is re-checked. You should not have to call any APIs during normal operations of your app, only when you want to do something like changing their password or primary email. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re_authenticate_a_user